# Is a master's degree in computer science relevant for working in sustainable living?

Tags: renewables, computing, education, academia

I'm currently at the end of computer science bachelor and not quite sure what to do after. In a way I'd like to continue with a Master's degree and at the same time help somehow for a more eco-friendly and sustainable world.

I know, for example, that informatics is needed when building systems like smart grid, weather/load prediction for electricity or even database building, data analysis in this area.
I am still wondering though if this won't over-qualify me in this area and maybe there is a study in which I approach other more relevant subjects for this. Note that I have up to a quarter of my study free choice of courses so I can choose the ones with power grids or similar things.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! A somewhat similar question was posted [here](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4709/what-can-i-do-as-a-developer-for-the-environment) and perhaps the answers to [this question](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2674/99) are also interesting for you. But more importantly, what aspect of sustainability do you find most interesting? Is it really smart grid, or perhaps something else?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I doubt that this question can be answered objectively. Key is really your interest! You state that you'd like to do a masters degree and that you're interested in high-tech fields related to sustainability. To me that sounds like two perfectly valid reasons to pursue that degree and join a job in sustainability after that. Notwithstanding it could be helpful to go for some courses outside CS with significance to sustainability (in a interdisciplinary perspective), e.g. ecology, environmental policies, systems engineering, or, or, or... to broaden your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely! While today we often think of sustainability considerations as secondary, up-and-coming, or even fringe, at some point in the future (hopefully soon!) they will be a standard and even primary component of any business model.

In the same way, information technology and computer science were once secondary considerations - and today they are central (or even primary) elements of any successful business or organization.

So, I challenge you not to think about specializing your career towards a sustainability perspective. Rather, the first step is to figure this out:

> I'm currently at the end of computer science bachelor and not quite sure what to do after.

What are you passionate about? What are you good at? What type of challenges do you enjoy solving? Find your skill set, and within that area, where do questions of sustainability apply? Any career path which you could imagine in the world today, will in the future require considerations of sustainability.

So, think of sustainability also on a personal level: what career choice will be sustainable *for you*? That is to say, what direction could you take your career that you will find fulfilling and challenging for years to come, so that you can continue to be as passionate about it years from now, as you are today? Bringing a sustainability perspective to something you are passionate about will bring about much more positive change in the world than trying to force yourself into a sustainability box that doesn't inspire you.

---

Something else to consider -- I took a few years to work after completing my BS before returning for an MS, and found that some experience out there in the "real world" helped focus my ambitions in grad school, and I've been able to get much more out of it than I believe I would have otherwise.